# how to access other .js file from React

Tags: reactjs

I want to access an access token stored in a file called `config.js` and `gitignore` it when I commit it.

This is how it looks like in the config

```
var config = {
  TOKEN : '____'
}
```

In my react,

```
import { config } from './config'
```

it imports it and when I do `config.TOKEN`, it gives me undefined.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export it:

```
export const config = {
  TOKEN : '____'
}
```

Alternatively,

```
const config = {
  TOKEN : '____'
}
export default config;

import config from './config';
```

Or you can use json file instead, then there'd be no need for export:

```
{
  "TOKEN": ''
}

import config from './config';
```

Lastly, with webpack you can create a `.env` file in project root folder with `REACT_APP_TOKEN=''` and the variable will be accessible with `process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN`.